# Two equal segments, two known angles, find angle in triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-transformation

[image]

This is the problem. I have tried the obvious without success. Drawing some perpendiculars (from A for example), I only know the angle $\sphericalangle ADC = 54 ^{\circ}$. How can I use the equality $AB = DC$?

Comment: A small point is that $\angle ADC = 55°$, not $54°$ as you state, based on $\angle ABC = 25°$ and $\angle BAD = 30°$. Also, it's not clear to me whether it's $DC$ or $BC$ which is equal in length to $AB$. Please clarify this. Thanks. Note that if it's $BC$, then you have an isosceles triangle, so it's quite simple that $x$ is $155/2°$, but then having $\angle BAD = 30°$ doesn't really do anything.

Comment: Thx for the comment. AB=DC. And the angle ABC is 24, not 25.

Comment: You are welcome. The writing made it seem like it was $25$ instead to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the law of sines we obtain:
$$\frac{AD}{\sin{x}}=\frac{DC}{\sin(126^{\circ}-x)}$$ and
$$\frac{AD}{\sin24^{\circ}}=\frac{AB}{\sin54^{\circ}}$$ and since $AB=DC$, we obtain:
$$\frac{\sin{x}}{\sin24^{\circ}}=\frac{\sin(126^{\circ}-x)}{\sin54^{\circ}}.$$
Can you end it now?

I got $x=30^{\circ}.$

Comment: If you do that trig, then you'll find that BD:DC is a ratio the OP might recognise. Wonder if there's a way to prove it geometrically. (From such a proof, @Michael's result would follow easily.)

Comment: @Rosie F I still don't see a geometric solution.

Comment: I really wonder how much are calculations here faster than pure geometric solution?

Answer (score 5):

Let's reformulate the problem.

> Let $\triangle ABC$ be such that $\angle ABC = 24^{\circ}$ and $\angle ACB = 30^{\circ}$ and $D$ is on $BC$ so that $AB = CD$.
>
> We have to prove $\angle BAD = 30^{\circ}$

[image]

**Solution:** Rotate $B$ around $A$ for $60^{\circ}$ to new point $E$. Then since $EA=EB$ and $$\angle AEB = 2\angle BCA$$ we see that $C$ is on circle with center at $E$ and radius $EA=EB = EC$. Then $CD = CE$, so $$\angle BCE = \angle CBE = 34^{\circ} \implies \angle EDC = \angle DEC = 72^{\circ}$$
Now this means that $$\angle BDE = 108^{\circ} \implies \angle BED = \angle EBD = 36^{\circ}$$
This means $BD = ED$, so so $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ADE$ are congruent (sss) and thus $\angle BAD = 30 ^{\circ}$.

Comment: Very nice solution! +1

Comment: Ah, glad that this angle problem with its rational answer has a geometrical solution. Classical elements of an adventitious-angle problem's solution: an equilateral triangle and a circumcentre. Pity it's analytical (with your reformulation) but it's sound nonetheless.

Comment: Which part in the solution is analytical? @RosieF

Comment: @greedoid You needed to know that the answer is $30^\circ$ in order to know to make $\angle ACB$ $30^\circ$ in your reformulation. I acknowledge that your solution is sound -- seeing as making $\angle ACB$ $30^\circ$ implies $\angle BAD=30^\circ$, the other constraints mean that, conversely, if $\angle BAD=30^\circ$ as specified, $\angle ACB=30^\circ$. But your reformulation is analytical in that it analysed the answer and proved it correct rather than synthesizing it directly.

Comment: I'm  not sure what you mean an but easy drawing make easy hypothethis it is 30 degree.@RosieF